# AWS getObject REST API request with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-sdk

I'm trying to send a request using nodejs in order to get an object from an AWS bucket.

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pass the ACCESS_KEY_ID & SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID in the request.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the credentials on the request yourself. Better do as [the docs say](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/?nc1=h_ls):

> Create a credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials on Mac/Linux or C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\credentials on Windows
>
> ```
> [default]
> aws_access_key_id = your_access_key
> aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_key
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As Miguel mentioned you can configure credentials in a config file or you can set the values as environment variables.

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEYID, 
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.getObject()
```

I prefer this method because it is easier to deploy to staging and production with different env variables on each server.

It also means if other devs are working on the project, they don't have to override any personal aws config files they already have.

And if you don't use it already, [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is a great package for setting your env variables in a `.env` file.

Comment: I'm familiar with this method, but the response returns a buffer which I'm having a hard time with. A regular REST API call just returns the file without a buffer.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue to your original question. You will need to provide information as to what you are trying to do with the object once you have downloaded it and what format you would like it to be in.